# how to zip a single directory rather than the whole directory structure

Tags: tar, filenames, archive

If I do:

```
tar -zcvf "/var/lib/mysql/backups/test1.tgz" "/var/lib/mysql/backups/20170214"
```

It creates a `tgz` file that when extracted contains `/var/lib/mysql/backups/20170214`

How can I do this so that the `tgz` file **ONLY** contains the `20170214` directory?

The problem is that when it comes to ungzipping it I need it in a different directory, e.g.

```
/var/lib/mysql/archives/20170214
```

Comment: cd to /var/lib/mysql/backups/ first, then tar czf /var/lib/mysql/backups/test1.tgz 20170214/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the `-C` option to change the directory.

From [man tar](https://linux.die.net/man/1/tar):

> -C, --directory=DIR
>       change to directory DIR

The following code should do the trick:

`tar -zcvf test1.tgz -C /var/lib/mysql/backups/20170214 .`

Don't forget the dot at then end, it selects the contents of the directory you have entered.